# How can I access snowflake from AWS glue?

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

In AWS glue, I am doing certain operations for which I need to access data tables in snowflake. I understand that I can use a whl for snowflake python connector. However, that method installs the snowflake package each time I run my process. Is there any other (more efficient ) way to access snowflake tables from AWS glue. Please note that I am using python as coding language in this case.

Comment: Do you mean the process documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-snowflake-home.html

Comment: If you are using Glue/Pyspark, follow the link shared by @NickW

if you are using Glue/PythonShell, you would need to pip install a snowflake package (from a whl file or from pypi) on the serverless Glue as the "server" does not have the Snowflake packages/drivers automatically installed. If you dont want to install each time a "server" is brought up, you need to use a EC2 instance that is always up and run the python job from that

Comment: I tried to setup the connection using nickW's shared link. However,  it didn't work. I might have made some mistakes. I used spark snowflake jar file in dependencies and used pyspark to access the database. Thanks.